# Is it possible to use parfor loops to increase the speed of training multiple neural networks in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, neural-network, parfor

I haven't obtained time improvements (sometimes it even takes longer) using a parfor loop in place of either of my for loops in the below code.

What i'd like is multiple networks to be being trained at the same time, so that I can run this code on a cluster, with  each cluster running a different set of neural networks.

If I change to `parfor Neurons = 1:n` I can tell the parfor loop is working because "Neurons" no longer changes sequentially/monotonically, as expected of parallel loops. However, only one "Neural Network Training (nntraintool)" GUI loads, which makes me think that only one worker is being deployed? On top of this I am gaining no time improvements. Is it possible to train multiple neural networks at the same time using different matlab workers? How?

Many many thanks.

```
tic
for init_conds = 1:m
   for no_neurons = 1:n

    net = patternnet(no_neurons);
    net = configure(net,inputs,targets);
    net.IW{1,1} = ...
    net.b{1,1} = ...
    net.LW{2,1} = ...
    net.b{2,1} = ...
    [net, tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);
    outputs = net(inputs);
    outputall = [outputall, outputs];

   end
end
toc
```

Comment: Check the task manager. Are the workers listed? And do they cause CPU-Load?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your response. They are not listed. I already have other MATLAB sessions running in the background, and 80-90% CPU load on every session, whether it is supposedly running in parallel or not.

Comment: Did you open a matlabpool?

Comment: No because it wouldn't work! I either get 'Undefined function or variable 'parpool'. Or `Error using matlabpool (line 134)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at
        java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:286)
         at
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:321)`

But having obtained faster speeds over a simple parfor loop I thought perhaps it wasn't necessary to open the pool. I do have the Parallel Processing Toolbox installed, as according to `ver`

Comment: This should fix it: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/919688
Hope I selected the right link from my history, currently can't reach mathworks.com

Comment: The link fixed all issues, thank you very much.